# How to add valid key without specifying value to a std::map?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a std::map, and I would like to add a valid key to iterate over it later, but without giving any value (it will be given later on in the course of the iterations).

This is how I do it for now :

```
std::vector<std::string> valid_keys;
//Fill... Then :
std::map<std::string, float> map;
for(size_t i = 0 ; i < valid_keys.size() ; ++i) {
    /*I don't want to do that because in fact I don't use a float type*/ 
    map[valid_keys[i]] = 0.f; //<- 
}
//Using :
for(std::map<std::string, float>::iterator it = map.begin() ; it != map.end() ; ++it) {
    it->second = 0; //Dummy
}
```

How can I do that, please ?

Thanks aforehand.

Comment: "/*I don't want to do that because in fact I don't use a float type*/" but you define `std::map<std::string, float>` why define it with a float if you don't want it to store floats?

Comment: It makes it more fun to try figuring out what the real issue is by obfuscating it with red herrings.  If it was too easy then you wouldn't appreciate the mystery.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "without giving any value" but if you mean without explicitly assigning a value then just do

```
map[valid_keys[i]];
```

This still works i.e. it creates a new entry in the map if there was not previously one with that key. The `operator[]` just returns a refernce to the value so that you can assign a new value to it but remember it's *already* been default constructed.

If, on the other hand, you mean you want to express that there is no meaningful value and it may or may not subsequently receive a valid value then see [@UncleBens` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577060/how-to-add-valid-key-without-specifying-value-to-a-stdmap/3577170#3577170).

Comment: I didn't even think of that (shame on me), thanks !

@Binary worrier : sorry for the question, I should have reformulated.

Comment: @Mister: `map[key];` is equivalent to `map[key] = value_type();`. In your example, that would be `map["key"]=float();`. Replace `float` with any other type (that has a default constructor).

Answer (score 7):

I suppose something that could help you out is [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <map>

class CantConstructMe
{
    CantConstructMe() {}
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int, boost::optional<CantConstructMe> > m;
    m[0];
}
```

The lack of available default constructor is not an issue, by default `optional` will be empty.

Answer (score 6):

> /* I don't want to do that because in fact I don't use a float type */

Then instead of `std::map` use the [`std::set`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set.html).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you really want a std::set or std::list of keys, and then iterate over that set later to create your map.

If for some reason this isn't acceptable, you could wrap your float with some type of object that implements operator float(), and various conversion functions for float, but also has a "good()" flag or somesuch.

If your final values are actually floats, you could initialize the values to +/- NaN as a simple placeholder.

I would say boost::optional is a better option for production code, but it depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

you can try by just making a temporary float or any data type and initialize the value of the map with it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
 map <string,map<int,vector<int>>> hen;
map<int ,vector<int>> m;

string s="egg";
hen[s]=m;
hen[s][1].push_back(5);




return 0;}
```

as you can see in this example I have made temporary map m to initialize it to hen[s]
similarly, you can create a temp float to initialize it to your map.