# How to initializing a shared_ptr map with optional values

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to initialize a shared_ptr with a map that has optional values. I'll initialize the values in a later stage of my program.

I read the following post and used it as a guide: [How to add valid key without specifying value to a std::map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577060/how-to-add-valid-key-without-specifying-value-to-a-stdmap)

But my situation is a little bit different because I'm using a shared_ptr. Without further ado, this is the code I wrote:

ShaderProgram.h

```
...
#include <map>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

typedef map<string, optional<GLuint> > attributes_map;

class ShaderProgram
{
public:
    ShaderProgram(vector<string> attributeList);
    ...
private:
    shared_ptr<attributes_map> attributes;
};
```

ShaderProgram.mm

```
ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram(vector<string> attributeList)
{
    // Prepare a map for the attributes
    for (vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i < attributeList.size(); i++)
    {
        string attribute = attributeList[i];
        attributes[attribute];
    }
}
```

The compiler notifies me about the following error: Type 'shared_ptr' does not provide a subscript operator.

Anyone an idea what might be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`attributes` is a `shared_ptr` and does not have `operator[]` but a `map` does. You need to dereference it:

```
(*attributes)[attribute];
```

Note no `map` object has been allocated for `attributes` in the constructor so once the compiler error is resolved you will get a runtime failure of some description. Either allocate a `map` instance:

```
ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram(vector<string> attributeList) :
    attributes(std::make_shared<attributes_map>())
{
    ...
}
```

or don't use a `shared_ptr`, as it is not obvious why dynamic allocation is required in this case:

```
private:
    attributes_map attributes;
```

Pass the `attributeList` by a reference to avoid unnecessary copying and as `const` as the constructor does not modify it:

```
ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram(const vector<string>& attributeList)
```